# Eclipse-like minimap ruler on PyCharm scrollbar

Tags: pycharm, scrollbar

I'm having a small issue in PyCharm : I want to go directly to the corresponding code line when clicking on the scrollbar.

Not just going a little up or down but at the point where I click, like with the Eclipse minimap ruler.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Just found an answer : it is possible by clicking with the middle mouse button.